# How to fix this column doesn't exist error in SQL?

Tags: sql

In the sales table, three columns are `btl_price`, `bottle_qty`, and `total`. The total for a transaction should be the product of `btl_price` and `bottle_qty`. How many transactions have a value of `total` that is not equal to `btl_price` times `bottle_qty`?

Here is the table:[image]

Here are my codes:

```
sql = """
Select (btl_price*bottle_qty) As total_sale, CAST(total AS money)
From sales
Where total != total_sale
"""
```

It keeps telling me "`column "total_sale" does not exist`".

Please help me to identify my mistakes.

PS: I code this in Jupyter Notebook. This is a practice of mine not in any DBMS.

Comment: You can't use 'display labels' (names specified with `AS` in the select-list) in the WHERE clause.  You'd have to write the expression (`btl_price * bottle_qty`) in the WHERE clause.  You may or may not be able to use display labels in ORDER BY or GROUP BY clauses — it depends on the DBMS.  You've not mentioned which DBMS you're using; please add that information because it helps produce focussed answers.

Comment: I use jupyter notebook for this code. This is a practice of mine.

Comment: Add the information to the question. You can edit your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use columns computed in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause (in SQL, the matter is evaluated before the former).

Also, you need proper type casting to compare money and numbers.

Finally, you need to turn on aggregation to compute the number of sales that satisfy the condition.

Assuming that you are using Postgres, that would be:

```
select count(*)
from sales 
where total::numeric <> btl_price::numeric * btl_quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE total !=(btl_price * bottle_qty)
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for contributing. but I tried yet it gives me "operator does not exist: money = numeric". I don't understand, both are "money" type.

Comment: @SongMei [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)